# Instantiating MediaDeviceInfo results in 'Illegal constructor'

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediadevices

Is it possible to instantiate my own instance of [MediaDeviceInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo)?  Both of these fail:

```
new MediaDeviceInfo();

new MediaDeviceInfo({
  deviceId: 'Brad Test',
  groupId: 'Brad Test',
  kind: 'audioinput',
  label: 'Brad Test'
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no constructor defined on the interface: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#device-info